# How to concatenate data frames from two different dictionaries into a new data frame in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, while-loop

This is my sample code

```
dataset_current=dataset_seq['Motor_Current_Average']
dataset_consistency=dataset_seq['Consistency_Average']

#technique with non-overlapping the values(for current)
dataset_slide=dataset_current.tolist()
from window_slider import Slider
import numpy
list = numpy.array(dataset_slide)
bucket_size = 336
overlap_count = 0
slider = Slider(bucket_size,overlap_count)
slider.fit(list)      
empty_dictionary = {}
count = 0
while True:
  count += 1
  window_data = slider.slide()
  empty_dictionary['df_current%s'%count] = window_data
  empty_dictionary['df_current%s'%count] =pd.DataFrame(empty_dictionary['df_current%s'%count])
  empty_dictionary['df_current%s'%count]= empty_dictionary['df_current%s'%count].rename(columns={0: 'Motor_Current_Average'})
  if slider.reached_end_of_list(): break
  locals().update(empty_dictionary)


#technique with non-overlapping the values(for consistency)
dataset_slide_consistency=dataset_consistency.tolist()
list = numpy.array(dataset_slide_consistency)
slider_consistency = Slider(bucket_size,overlap_count)
slider_consistency.fit(list)      
empty_dictionary_consistency = {}
count_consistency = 0
while True:
  count_consistency += 1
  window_data_consistency = slider_consistency.slide()
  empty_dictionary_consistency['df_consistency%s'%count_consistency] = window_data_consistency
  empty_dictionary_consistency['df_consistency%s'%count_consistency] =pd.DataFrame(empty_dictionary_consistency['df_consistency%s'%count_consistency])
  empty_dictionary_consistency['df_consistency%s'%count_consistency]= empty_dictionary_consistency['df_consistency%s'%count_consistency].rename(columns={0: 'Consistency_Average'})
  if slider_consistency.reached_end_of_list(): break
  locals().update(empty_dictionary_consistency)
import pandas as pd
output_current ={}
increment = 0
while True:
   increment +=1
   output_current['dataframe%s'%increment] = pd.concat([empty_dictionary_consistency['df_consistency%s'%count_consistency],empty_dictionary['df_current%s'%count]],axis=1)
```

My question is i have two dictionaries that contains 79 data frames in each one of them namely "**empty_dictionary_consistency**" and "**empty_dictionary**" . I want to create a new data frame for each one of them so that it concatenates df1 from **empty_dictionary_consistency** with df1 from **empty_dictionary** .So , it will start from concatenating df1 from **empty_dictionary_consistency** with df1 from **empty_dictionary** till df79 from **empty_dictionary_consistency** with df79 from **empty_dictionary**  . I tried using while loop to increment it but does not shows any output.

```
output_current ={}
increment = 0
while True:
   increment +=1
   output_current['dataframe%s'%increment] = pd.concat([empty_dictionary_consistency['df_consistency%s'%count_consistency],empty_dictionary['df_current%s'%count]],axis=1)
```

Can anyone help me regarding this? How can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not near my computer now, so I can not test the code, but it seems that the problem is in indices. In the last loop, on every iteration you increment a variable called 'increment', but you still use indices from previous loops for dictionaries that you want to concatenate.  Try to change variables that you use for indexing all dictionaries to 'increment'.
And one more thing - I can't see when this loop is going to finish?

UPD
I mean this:

```
length = len(empty_dictionary_consistency)
increment = 0 
while increment < length: 
    increment +=1
    output_current['dataframe%s'%increment] = pd.concat([empty_dictionary_consistency['df_consistency%s'%increment],empty_dictionary['df_current%s'%increment]],axis=1)
```

While iterating over your dictionaries you should use a variable that you increment as an index in all three dictionaries. And as soon as you do not use a Slider object in the loop, you have to stop it when the first dictionary is over.

Comment: Can you please try to execute the code it will really help you to understand. Also can you write the code so that i can better understand. It's a bit confusing.. Or else is there any other way to do what i wanted to do.

Comment: @Logica I can't run the code rigth now, but I edited my answer - wrote what I mean in code.

Comment: @Logica please, tell me if the code had solved your problem or not when you try it.

Comment: one question where are you using i variable ?
while i < length: This i isn't used any where in the code.  i isn't defined any where

Comment: i solved the issue by editing your code `output_current ={}
length = len(empty_dictionary_consistency)
increment = 0 
i = 0
while i < length: 
    increment +=1
    output_current['dataframe%s'%increment] = pd.concat([empty_dictionary_consistency['df_consistency%s'%increment],empty_dictionary['df_current%s'%increment]],axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks anyways for your help Vlad Riabets :)

Comment: @Logica I'm glad that my code helped you) Of cause you are right about i variable - it must be increment. This is just my habit of using i in loops.

Comment: Accepted your answer :)

Comment: @Logica Cool :)